# Does signing an assembly or an exe with a digital certificate makes it secure against tampering attacks?

Tags: security, digital-certificate, tampering

I tried creating a temporary certificate using makecert and creating a spc from the certificate using cert2spc. I signed some exe with the generated spc. I then use the binary editor in VS 2008 to flip some bits (tampered it) in the exe. To my surprise I was able to execute the application.

I was expecting that the system will detect the tampering and will complain. Hence the question.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No,  because any code in the binary to check the signature can also be tampered with.

I recommend obtaining a copy of IDA Pro and disassembling one of your binaries.  After you have the raw assembler you can edit specific opcodes using a hex editor.  In short,  this is the tactic that the cracker community uses.  I don't believe that there will ever be a way to stop this, the ps3 and xbox360 both use digital signatures to protect their binaries,  but this doesn't stop piracy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wonder about what kind of tampering attack the digital signatures can with stand. Am I doing anything wrong in a way I am assigning signatures to my binaries. I am doing this just for the purpose of learning.

Comment: Learning is awesome,  I totally support that.  The problem with this scenario is that the attacker has full control over the system,  he owns the computer and processor and the binary,  so as a software developer you don't have the control.  Where digital signature works exceedingly well is in network communications.  SSL/TLS which powers HTTPS would not be possible without digital signatures.   The difference is that the attacker is on the outside looking in on 2 people that want to communicate in a secure manner.